# crystal report 9 printing string

Tags: crystal-reports

I have column its name 'owner' and its has the following vlaue

```
               ownerName
               -------- 
                 Koni 
                 Sally
                 Jimmi
                 Jone
                 Sami
```

and i want to print this value in crystal report as following using formula
              ownerName

```
           Koni 
           --Sally
           ----Jimmi
           ------Jone
           --------Sami
```

thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the following formula criteria:

```
If (RecordNumber > 1) Then
ReplicateString("-", RecordNumber) + {DatabaseFieldName}
Else
{DatabaseFieldName}
```